# psql option like --defaults-file for mysql client

Tags: psql

Is there any option for psql client like --defaults-file with mysql. I work with plenty of databases and a lot of application server and I would like storing my credential details in cfg files and execute psql like I do with mysql:

> mysql --defaults-file=ABC.cfg

I know who to use alias but I don't want to maintain connection details on .bashrc on each server I work on.

Comment: I don't know what that defaults file does, but maybe you are looking for [.psqlrc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.20.10) or a [service file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html)

Comment: --defaults-file allows you to give connection parameters like host, user, database, port

Comment: Then it should be the service file.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Ok please give me an exemple to ensure it fits the requirement.

Comment: Since the requirement is not quite clear, I cannot do that. I don't feel like reading up on MySQL just for this question.

Comment: Ok, so how to run a command with psql and a service file as parameter ?